# How to add context menu, autoComplete, onChange Event in ADF CodeEditor?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, oracle-adf, valuechangelistener

I am using jDeveloper 12.1.2. I am not using ADF BC,  ADF DC, ADF AM.
I am trying to create a Code Editor for XML using ADF-Faces that should have functionality like

1. autocomplete closing tag
2. as soon as codeEditor is edited it should be marked as Changed.
3. right click options for code editor(specific to the  functionality of code).

I am unable to fetch Caret position for adding autocomplete of closing tag.
ValueChangeListener are getting triggered once the user tabs out the codeEditor or clicks outside codeEditor. I want to call valueChangeListener as soon as editing begins so that I can mark editor as dirty.
I tried adding context menu. I am getting an error : ShowPopupBehavior is not a valid child of af:codeEditor.
Also, I want to add some javascript code in codeEditor but I am getting an error : af:clientListener is not a valid child of af:codeEditor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

af:codeEditor has its limitiations. You can not customize it much on top of what comes out of the box.